# Conditional evaluation of a conditional evaluation

Tags: ruby, syntax, conditional-statements

What might be a more succinct, rubyesque way of expressing this bit of code?

```
if should_be_admin
  result = user and user.admin?
else
  result = not user.nil?
end
```

Comment: Perhaps `result = should_be_admin ? (user and user.admin?) : !!user`. `!!` converts a truthy value to `true` and a falsy value (`nil` or `false`) to `false`.

Comment: If you give us what `should_be_admin` and `admin?` return, we can give better answers.

Comment: @CarySwoveland sounds simple enough!

Comment: @sawa, I don't think that matters. As one can see, they are both boolean, so it can either be true or false!

Comment: It does matter to know that they are both boolean. "As one can see"--Where?

Comment: Alf, @sawa had a point, but I changed my comment while he was posting.

Comment: I thought it was obvious they were boolean?? should_be_admin is against an 'if', and the admin method has a '?'

Comment: Not at all. It is okay for a non-boolean to appear in a condition. And how is the `?` relevant?

Comment: Does it matter as long as they're treated as truthy/falsy? And have I got my ruby wrong to expect a method ending with ? to return a boolean?

Comment: Agreed. But you've sold me the first one @CarySwoveland, you could perhaps move that to an official answer I can then accept!

Comment: Please wait at least a couple of hours before accepting any answer. You don't want to discourage other answers or short-circuit those still preparing answers.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense, I've 'de-accepted' your answer to let others contribute. Good point! Thanks.

Comment: @sawa Very curious to know why you think it matters. Have I understood something incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

```
result = should_be_admin ? (user and user.admin?) : !!user
```

or

```
result = user ? (should_be_admin ? user.admin? : true) : false
```

`!!` converts a truthy value to `true` and a falsy value (`nil` or `false`) to `false`.

Comment: Nested ternary statements become difficult to decipher and maintain.

Comment: @theTinMan, my brain must work differently; in terms of readability I see no difference between these ternary expressions and their `if..else..end` counterparts. I could see a problem if the `true/false` clauses were long or if the expressions were deeply nested (but I don't like deeply-nest conditionals generally).